# Get all ways to express a number as a product of two integers

Tags: c++, factors

I've been playing with finding divisors of numbers recently and decided to try and make a program, which prints all ways to express a number N as a product of two integers. I wrote one which works on positive numbers and only considers positive numbers to make up the product.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int root = std::sqrt(n);
    for(int i = 1; i <= root; i++)
    {
        if(n % i != 0)
            continue;

        int j = n / i;  
        std::cout << i << ", " << j << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code above just finds all divisors of N and prints them as pairs. It works fine, but I wanted to try and make it find all possible ways to get to N, not only with positive numbers.

For example, if I input 10 in the program above, the results will be (1, 10), (2, 5); These are correct, but there are other ways to multiply two numbers and get to 10. It involves negative numbers: (-1, -10), (-2, -5) are also solutions, since when you multiply two negative numbers, you end up with a positive one.

If I wanted the program to only work on positive N values but also find negative multiples, I could just print the negative versions of i and j, since you can only get to a positive number by either multiplying two positive or two negative together.

That works, but now I want to get this code to work on negative N values. For example, an expected output for N = -10 would be: (-1, 10), (1, -10), (2, -5), (-2, 5);

The problem is, the algorithm above can only find positive divisors for positive numbers, since it involves square root, which is only defined for positive numbers, and the loop starts at a positive and ends at a positive.

I noticed that I can just calculate the square root of the absolute value of N, then make the loop start at -root and end at root to go over the negative divisors of N as well. I had to make sure to skip 0, though, because division with 0 isn't defined and that made it crash. The code I ended up with looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int root_n = std::sqrt(std::abs(n));
    for(int i = -root_n; i <= root_n; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0 || n % i != 0)
            continue;

        int j = n / i;  
        std::cout << i << ", " << j << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It worked properly for all the tests I came up with, but I am not sure if it's the best way to write it. Is there anything that I can improve?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Tried using std::div as suggested by Caleth (also used ReSharper addon in VS to give me refactoring suggestions):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    const int sqrt_n = std::sqrt(std::abs(n));
    for(auto i = -sqrt_n; i <= sqrt_n; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
            continue;

        const auto div_res = std::div(n, i);
        if (div_res.rem)
            continue;

        std::cout << i << ", " << div_res.quot << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of calculating the remainder, then calculating the quotient, I can just do a single call to std::div, which returns a struct, containing both values.

Comment: You may want to look at [`std::div`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div), which returns a struct with both the quotient and the remainder in one call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A major observation is that the negative divisors and the positive divisors of a number are the same, except for sign. You could save half of the time if you looked only at positive numbers and handled signs on your own. For example,

```cpp
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int root_n = std::sqrt(std::abs(n));

    for(int i = 1; i <= root_n; i++) \\ don't loop over negative numbers now
    {
        if(n % i != 0) \\ not necessary to check for 0 anymore
            continue;

        int j = n / i;  
        std::cout << i << ", " << j << "\n";
        std::cout << -i << ", " << -j << "\n";  \\ corresponding negative
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You might notice that I removed `std::endl` --- you don't really need to flush the stream that often. It's faster to let output buffer as it wants.

If you are looking for other ways to modify your program, you might try finding the prime factorization and then computing lists of divisors from it. For large, highly composite inputs, this will be faster. But it's also quite different.

Comment: Now that I think about it, that actually makes sense! Thanks!